# Programming Shimmer 3D sensor in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently starting a Unity project which use some sensors from Shimmer Sensor.
I cant start my project properly because i don't have enough documentation about their C# API.

So I'm looking for someone who can share a project made with those kind of sensor, at least the initialization part, and the connection.

My code:

```
Shimmer Shim = new Shimmer ("Shimmer3-8615","COM6");//Initialise the sensor for the connection
ObjectCluster Test = new ObjectCluster ("COM6","Shimmer3-8615");//Contain the Data from the sensor

public float speed;

void Awake ()//Launch when the programme start
{
    Shim.Connect ();//Connect the object to the sensor with bluetooth
}

void FixedUpdate ()//Start whenever he receive data
{
    float movehorizontal;
    float movevertical;
    movehorizontal = float.Parse((Test.GetData("Low Noise Accelerometer X", "RAW")).GetData().ToString());
    movevertical = float.Parse((Test.GetData("Low Noise Accelerometer Y", "RAW")).GetData().ToString());//Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")
    float up = float.Parse((Test.GetData("Low Noise Accelerometer Z", "RAW")).GetData().ToString());//0.0f

    Vector3 mouvement = new Vector3 (movehorizontal,up,movevertical);
    rigidbody.AddForce (mouvement * speed *Time.deltaTime);

}
```

When the .connect executes itself, I get a null object exception.
The connection is made with bluetooth on the COM port 6